# Bootstrap row - 2 columns (text right, image left) - Need image fill up the left columns properly and be responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I’m trying for hours now, almost a day and I try everything but probably the right way to do it...

**This is my simplify html:**

```
 <div class="row block-ditributeur">
    <div class="col-lg-8 image">
        <div class="col-image-container"><img src=“MY-IMAGE-HERE.jpg"  class="img-fluid" dir="ltr" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-container flexcenter-container">
        <div class="text flexcenter-item center">
            MY TEXT HERE
        </div>
    </div>
```

[This is what it look like, without any css (only img-fluid class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNXcH.jpg)

Whatever I do, the image don’t want to correctly match the height of the text square on the right (even if I enter pixel values), be the correct ratio and be responsive and look good when the columns collapse. I can’t even make it fill the space on desktop view...

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set the height of the entire row.

```
 <div class="row block-ditributeur" style="height: 150px;">
```

OR

Try giving an id to the container divs of both elements and then setting height with CSS.

Something like:

```
<div class="row block-ditributeur">
   <div class="col-lg-8 image" id="imagecontainer">
       <div class="col-image-container"><img src=“MY-IMAGE-HERE.jpg"  class="img- 
        fluid" dir="ltr" /></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 text-container flexcenter-container" id="textcontainer">
        <div class="text flexcenter-item center">
            MY TEXT HERE
        </div>
   </div>
```

and then in the CSS file:

```
#imagecontainer,
#textcontainer{
      height: 150px;
}
```